# C Delete last n characters from file

Tags: c, file, char, truncate, mmap

I need to delete the last n characters from a file using C code. At fist I was trying to use '\b', but it returns a Segmentation Fault. I have seen interesting answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584639/truncate-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311683/is-there-any-basic-way-to-delete-something-from-opened-file), but I would prefer to use `mmap` function to do this, if it's possible. I know it could be simpler to truncate the file by creating a temp file, and writing chars to temp until some offset of the original file. The problem is I don't seem to understand how to use `mmap` function to do this, can't see what parameters I need to pass to that function, specially `address`, `length` and `offset`. From what I've read, I should use `MAP_SHARED` in `flags` and `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` in `protect`.

The function definition says:

```
void * mmap (void *address, size_t length, int protect, int flags, int filedes, off_t offset)
```

Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * InputFile;
    off_t position;
        int charsToDelete;

    if ((InputFile = fopen(argv[1],"r+")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("tdes: file not found: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
                charsToDelete = 5;
        fseeko(InputFile,-charsToDelete,SEEK_END);
        position = ftello(InputFile);
        printf("Pos: %d\n",(int)position);
        int i;
        //for(i = 0;i < charsToDelete;i++)
        //{
        //  putc(InputFile,'\b');
        //}
    }
    fclose(InputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use:

```
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>

   int truncate(const char *path, off_t length);
   int ftruncate(int fd, off_t length);
```

like for instance:

```
    charsToDelete = 5;
    fseeko(InputFile,-charsToDelete,SEEK_END);
    position = ftello(InputFile);
    ftruncate(fileno(InputFile), position);
```

Comment: I Used `ftruncate(fileno(InputFile), position);` as you suggested and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: how would you delete the first n characters?

Comment: For other weary wanderers; this is not C99 compliant

Answer (score 3):

Read all but `n` bytes from the file and write to a temporary file, close the original file, rename temporary file as original file.

Or use e.g. [`truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) or similar function if you have it.

---

Also, failure to open the file doesn't have to be that it can't be found, You should check [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) on failure to see what the error is. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string from the error code.

Comment: Could be some sort of permissions issue.

Comment: Because I can't access the filename in the real code, I used ftruncate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `mmap` does not allow you to change size of underlying file object.

Instead, I would recommend to simply truncate your file, use something like this:

```
truncate(filename, new_length);
```

Comment: I thought I could use `mmap` for that. In which cases using that function would seem a good idea? When I need to make some character shift in the file? Like when using `memmove`?

Comment: because `mmap` maps file contents into memory (you can use pointers with known memory block size), you must remove mapping *before* you change file size by writing more data to it or by using `truncate`. If you want to manipulate file contents quickly, `mmap` is good and fast method. But if you need to change file size, change it upfront, and then use `mmap`.